How to run ROS multimaster on noetic?
I am trying to run multimaser for ros-noetic between two Docker containers. I am following the instructions from this pdf section 3. This is my Dockerfile
FROM ros:noetic

ARG ROS_MASTER_URI=http://0.0.0.0:11311

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ros-noetic-fkie-master-sync && \
    apt-get install -y ros-noetic-fkie-master-discovery

ENV ROS_MASTER_URI ${ROS_MASTER_URI}

CMD roscore

I build the image like this
docker image build --build-arg="ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.20.0.5:11311" -t multicast:test .
I then run roscore in the container.
docker run -it --rm --name test-host1 --sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=0  --hostname testHost1 --network ros-network --ip 172.20.0.5 multicast:test
Then I run docker exec to start up another terminal for that container.
docker exec -it -e PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/ros/noetic/bin:/opt/ros/noetic/lib test-host1 /bin/bash
Once I am in the terminal, I discovered that I have to load the dynamic ROS libraries. So in the /etc/ld.so.conf.d I create a file roslibs.conf with the contents
/opt/ros/noetic/lib
I then run
ldconfig
Then from section 3.3 of the pdf I run
rosrun master_discovery_fkie master_discovery _mcast_group:=224.0.0.1
and I get an error
[rospack] Error: package 'master_discovery_fkie' not found
I found a directory named
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/fkie_master_discovery
with the contents
__init__.py  __pycache__  common.py  filter_interface.py  interface_finder.py  master_discovery.py  master_info.py  master_monitor.py  udp.py  zeroconf.py

The contents of the __init__.py file is quite large. Can I build a package from this? If so how?
